# iPhone 6 shuts down when locking screen

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a problem with an iPhone 6, every time I lock the screen with the lock button or with AssistiveTouch the phone will shut down.
Is there any solution or is it an hardware problem?

Comment: By shutdown you mean that if you turn it on again you see the Apple icon first?

Comment: @patrix exactly

Comment: Have you tried to reset it to factory defaults (can backup and restore from that backup) ?

Comment: if factory defaults don't fix the problem you should try visiting a genius store if you're close by